# How to solve this recurrence T(n)=2T(n)(n/2) + nlogn

Tags: algorithm, big-o, substitution, divide-and-conquer

[image: A recurrence relation with a likely typo]

using the substitution method and use the tightest big
O(n) notation to represent solution.
Is there any problem with the formula of the question?

i have no idea. T(n)=2T(n/2) + nlogn,questions should look like this, right?

Comment: As written, T(n) depends on T(n) which is probably a typo.

Comment: What did the person who gave you that say when you asked them?

Comment: Yes, it should almost certainly be `T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + n log n`.

Comment: (Based on other strange formatting choices, I suspect a copy-paste error by someone using, but not entirely familiar with, (La)TeX.)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you meant to say that `T(n)=2T(n/2)+nlog(n)`. Apologies for the ugly formatting, this site doesn't have MathJax

Because `n\log(n)` is not strictly polynomial, we can't use the Master Theorem, rather we need [Akra-Bazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

In this case we have that `g(n)=nlog(n)`, `a=2`, `b=1/2`, which means that `ab^p=1` if `p=1`. This means that the solution to our asymptotics is

`T(n)=Θ(n(1+\int_1^n log(t)/t dt))=Θ(nlog^2(n))`

Comment: Master theorem does work here. What makes you think it requires something strictly polynomial?

Comment: Oh damn you're right I can't read. The answer is still the same though